# Regex won't match whitespace character with [\r\n\t\f\s]

Tags: java, regex, string, newline, whitespace

This is likely a very simple fix but I can't figure it out!

I'm trying to match (up to) 3 capitalized words in a row given the following text.

`Russell Lake West`.  The match should include all 3 words.

This regex will match the first 2 words but not the third ([demo here](https://regex101.com/r/gD5jU9/1)):

`(([A-Z][a-z]+)\s{0,2}([A-Z][a-z]+)?\s{0,2}([A-Z][a-z]+)?)`

This regex **will** match all 3 words, but I had to copy/paste the whitespace between `Lake` and `West` for it to work ([demo here](https://regex101.com/r/qS7aO1/1)):

`(([A-Z][a-z'-]+)\s{0,2}([A-Z][a-z'-]+)? \s{0,2}([A-Z][a-z'-]+)?)`

```
                                       ^ pasted it here
```

So I assumed that maybe the whitespace isn't being treated as whitespace, but perhaps a newline character or similar, so I tried this ([demo here)](https://regex101.com/r/bM6kD5/1):

`[\r\n\t\f\s]West`

But it doesn't recognize any of those characters before `West`, thus returning no results.

Why can't regex101 or Java recognize this apparent whitespace between `Lake` and `West`? What's a reliable way to handle this?

Comment: Updated: https://regex101.com/r/gD5jU9/2

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting approach. Except it also matches non-capitalized words. Appreciate it either way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many kinds of spaces. The one you are using in your [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gD5jU9/1) is [non-breaking](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) one (indexed as 160 in Unicode table) which doesn't belong to `\s` (whitespaces character class) as it doesn't represent place on which we can expect text to be split into separate parts like lines.
BTW `\s` already represents: `\r` `\n` `\t` `\f`.

To match it you can use `\p{Zs}` class.
You can also combine both `\s` and `\p{Zs}` classes with `[\\p{Zs}\\s]`.